# Unable to successfully migrate a project: TF201077: The work item type cannot be found

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I've successfully migrated both stock and bespoke projects but I'm having trouble with one project I can't move based on the same config file (so it's probably not the config).

It looks like it's unable to save the work item. I've tried project to project in the same org using the same process, org to org, and removing any iterations. I just get the same error.

The work items I'm migrating are extremely basic tasks/stories with no bespoke fields populated.

I'm getting the following:

```
[11:33:24 ERR] Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemTypeDeniedOrNotExistException: TF201077: The work item type  cannot be found. It may have been renamed or destroyed.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.get_Type()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemFieldData.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Internals.IWorkItemOpenFieldDataHelper.SetLatestData(Dictionary`2 latestData)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Internals.WorkItemHelper.LoadWorkItemFieldData(IRowSetCollectionHelper tables, IWorkItemOpenFieldDataHelper helper)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.LoadWorkItemFromRowSetInternal(Int32 rev, Nullable`1 asof, IWorkItemRowSets witem)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem..ctor(WorkItemStore store, Int32 id, Int32 revision)
   at MigrationTools.TfsExtensions.GetRevision(WorkItemData context, Int32 rev) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\TfsExtensions.cs:line 35
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.ReplayRevisions(List`1 revisionsToMigrate, WorkItemData sourceWorkItem, WorkItemData targetWorkItem) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 600
```

and at the end:

```
[11:33:25 ERR] Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags saveFlags)
   at MigrationTools.TfsExtensions.SaveToAzureDevOps(WorkItemData context) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\TfsExtensions.cs:line 76
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.ReplayRevisions(List`1 revisionsToMigrate, WorkItemData sourceWorkItem, WorkItemData targetWorkItem) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 643
[11:33:25 INF] ===============================================================
[11:33:25 WRN] Work Item is not ready to save as it has some invalid fields. This may not result in an error. Enable LogLevel as 'Debug' in the config to see more.
[11:33:25 ERR] Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags saveFlags)
   at MigrationTools.TfsExtensions.SaveToAzureDevOps(WorkItemData context) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\TfsExtensions.cs:line 76
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.<ProcessWorkItemAsync>d__35.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 486
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags saveFlags)
   at MigrationTools.TfsExtensions.SaveToAzureDevOps(WorkItemData context) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\TfsExtensions.cs:line 76
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.<ProcessWorkItemAsync>d__35.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 486
[11:33:25 ERR] Could not save migrated work item 35, an exception occurred.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.<ProcessWorkItemAsync>d__35.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 531
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.InternalExecute() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 205
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.<ProcessWorkItemAsync>d__35.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 531<---
[11:33:25 WRN] The following items could not be migrated: 35
[11:33:25 INF] DONE in 00:00:05.6093139
[11:33:25 FTL] Error while running WorkItemMigration
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.<ProcessWorkItemAsync>d__35.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 531
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.InternalExecute() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 225
   at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Processors.MigrationProcessorBase.Execute() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\_EngineV1\Processors\MigrationProcessorBase.cs:line 47
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.<ProcessWorkItemAsync>d__35.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 531<---
[11:33:25 ERR] WorkItemMigration The Processor MigrationEngine entered the failed state...stopping run
[11:33:25 INF] Application is shutting down...
[11:33:25 INF] Terminating: Application forcebly closed.
[11:33:25 INF] Application Ending
[11:33:25 INF] The application ran in 00:00:10.7989077 and finished at 07/27/2022 11:33:25
```

The config is:

```
{
  "ChangeSetMappingFile": null,
  "Source": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/XXXX/",
    "Project": "XXXX",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "AuthenticationMode": "AccessToken",
    "PersonalAccessToken": "XXXXX",
    "PersonalAccessTokenVariableName": "",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Area",
      "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
  },
  "Target": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/XXXX/",
    "Project": "XXXX",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "AuthenticationMode": "AccessToken",
    "PersonalAccessToken": "XXXX",
    "PersonalAccessTokenVariableName": "",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Area",
      "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
  },
  "FieldMaps": [
  ],
  "GitRepoMapping": null,
  "LogLevel": "Information",
  "CommonEnrichersConfig": null,
  "Processors": [
    {
      "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "Enabled": true,
      "ReplayRevisions": true,
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "WIQLQueryBit": "AND  [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] = '' AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan','Shared Steps','Shared Parameter','Feedback Request')",
      "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
      "LinkMigration": true,
      "AttachmentMigration": true,
      "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
      "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": true,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
      "AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
      "AttachRevisionHistory": false,
      "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false,
      "GenerateMigrationComment": true,
      "WorkItemIDs": null,
      "MaxRevisions": 0,
      "NodeStructureEnricherEnabled": null,
      "UseCommonNodeStructureEnricherConfig": false,
      "NodeBasePaths": [
        "Product\\Area\\Path1",
        "Product\\Area\\Path2"
      ],
      "AreaMaps": {},
      "IterationMaps": {},
      "MaxGracefulFailures": 0
    }
  ],
  "Version": "12.0",
  "workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
  "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
    "sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName"
  },
  "Endpoints": {
    "InMemoryWorkItemEndpoints": [
      {
        "Name": "Source",
        "EndpointEnrichers": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "Target",
        "EndpointEnrichers": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Posting an answer in case anyone else had the same problem.

My issue was in the config file after all. It had example data under the node base paths:

```
  "NodeBasePaths": [
    "Product\\Area\\Path1",
    "Product\\Area\\Path2"
  ],
```

and that prevented the node mapping which caused the save to fail and produced the error. Simply removing all data in that section if I'm not using it solved the problem.