# TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags saveFlags) Unable to migrate

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I am trying to migrate work items type Product backlog item to another project as User story.

TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags saveFlags) Unable to migrate

Comment: I think this might be the same challenge as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73137313/unable-to-successfully-migrate-a-project-tf201077-the-work-item-type-cannot-be

Comment: Please report bugs with OSS tools to the project maintainer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug report for an OSS tool.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have the answer to your challenge as I was facing the same one. Answered here:

[Unable to successfully migrate a project: TF201077: The work item type cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73137313/unable-to-successfully-migrate-a-project-tf201077-the-work-item-type-cannot-be)

My issue was in the config file after all. It had example data under the node base paths:

"NodeBasePaths": [
"Product\Area\Path1",
"Product\Area\Path2"
],
and that prevented the node mapping which caused the save to fail and produced the error. Simply removing all data in that section if I'm not using it solved the problem.